# Access VBA Loop through Query help

Tags: ms-access, vba, loops

I have a form (Cobind_frmMain) that allows the user to create a pool of titles that are attached to it. So there is a top level Pool Name (TopLvlPoolName) and on a subform, the titles are added to it. What I need is to issue a Report for each of the titles. I have the report and queries all set up. Right now, the report will show all the titles in one file. The titles are in a field called "CatCode".

What I need is the following:
1. Save each title as a PDF and save it to our server.
2. Open email and attach the PDF.
3. Repeat until all titles are done.

**EDIT:** This is what I have so far for code and the error message I still get is: "Too Few Parameters" on the Set Recordset line. I'm trying to set the parameter in the strSQL line. I want the PartPoolName (in Cobind_qryReport, a query) to equal the TopLvlPoolName on the open form. The SQL for Cobind_qryReport is listed below:

```
Private Sub btn_Run_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database  
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset  
Dim strSQL As String  
Set db = CurrentDb  

strSQL = "Select * FROM Cobind_qryReport WHERE PartPoolName = " & Me.TopLvlPoolName

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

On Error GoTo Err_PO_Click

If MsgBox("Do you wish to issue the cobind invites?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirmation Required") = vbYes Then

 rs.MoveFirst

  Do While Recordset.EOF = False

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Cobind_rptMain", acFormatPDF, "K:\OB MS Admin\Postage\CoBind Opportunities\Sent Invites\" & [CatCode] & "_" & [PartPoolName] & "Cobind Invite_" & Format(Now(), "mmddyy") & ".pdf"

    DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Cobind_rptMain", acFormatPDF, , , , [CatCode] & "_" & [PartPoolName] & " Cobind Invite", "Please find the cobind invite attached. Response is needed by " & [RSVP] & ". Thank you.", True

    Recordset.MoveNext

  Loop

End If


Exit_PO_Click:
    MsgBox ("It didn't work")
    Exit Sub

Err_PO_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_PO_Click
End Sub
```

Cobind_qryReport SQL:
SELECT tblEvents.EventTitle, Cobind_tblPartic.CatCode, Cobind_tblPartic.CodeQty, Cobind_tblPartic.PartPoolName, Cobind_tblTopLvl.RSVP, Cobind_tblPartic.ID
FROM Cobind_tblTopLvl, Cobind_tblPartic INNER JOIN tblEvents ON Cobind_tblPartic.CatCode = tblEvents.EventCode
GROUP BY tblEvents.EventTitle, Cobind_tblPartic.CatCode, Cobind_tblPartic.CodeQty, Cobind_tblPartic.PartPoolName, Cobind_tblTopLvl.RSVP, Cobind_tblPartic.ID
ORDER BY Cobind_tblPartic.ID;

Thank you again for all your help!

Comment: Please make sure and specify the types for your Dim statements.  It will save you heartache and running time.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand the Option Explicit. Where exactly would I put that?

Answer (score 1):

You're query `Cobind_qryReport` has a parameter that you need to set. if you want to know the parameter name try the following code

```
   Dim qdf As QueryDef
   Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Cobind_qryReport")

    If qdf.Parameters.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox (qdf.Parameters(0).Name)
    End If
```

**Update**
Since you know you've got a parameter doing `select * from Cobind_qryReport` it might just be easier to set the parameter and then use the qdf to open the recordset e.g.

```
   Dim rs as DAO.Recordset
   Dim qdf As QueryDef
   Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Cobind_qryReport")

   qdf.Parameters(0).Value = 7832
   Set foo = qdf.OpenRecordset()
```

Note: you can use the parameter name in the place of the ordinal when setting the parametervalue

e.g. `qdf.Parameters("Foo").value = 7832`

Comment: +1 It might be better as `qdf.Parameters.Count > 0` ... in case the query includes more than one parameter.

Comment: OK, so I know I have a parameter. Are you saying that it's throwing off the Recordset?

Comment: @HansUp, You're right of course(updated my answer) but we know its exactly one because the error says "Too few parameters. Expected 1"

Comment: @Len D'Alberti Yes, if the query expects a parameter, OpenRecordset will not work the way you're trying to use it.  Why not just revise Cobind_qryReport so it doesn't require a parameter?  If you need help, show us the SQL and tell us which name Access thinks is the parameter.

Comment: @Len D'Alberti I've updated my answer to show how you would specify the parameter and open a recordset. Or you can do what HansUp suggested and rewrite the SQL so it doesn't need the parameter

Comment: OK, so I removed the parameter from the query. I will try adding in the parameter into the code. But right now when I try to run the code, it gives me the error message, "MS Access can't find the field "|" referred to in your expression", then goes to Exit_PO_Click.

Comment: And thank you both for your help. It's very insightful. I'm looking to go into a career of programming and your answers are helping me logically think things through!

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but what does the "7832" represent?

Comment: @Len D'Alberti 7832 is an arbitrary value. It could be anything I meant to as a demonstration

Comment: Nice job, Conrad.  Sorry I could only give you one +1.

Comment: @HansUp thanks. BTW without your answer I never would have suspected a parameter on the query. This is why I gave you a +1 as well (but its still negated by the previous down vote)

Comment: OK, I'm having trouble with this now:
qdf.Parameters(PartPoolName).Value = Me.TopLvlPoolName
Set PartPoolName = qdf.OpenRecordset()
It tells me item is not found. So frustrating! PartPoolName is the field in the query that the TopLvlPoolName acts as a parameter on.

Comment: @Len D'Alberti  Can you edit the original post, and add the new code?